# Sorting numbers in a matrix by moving an empty entry through other entries is not always possible .

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, permutations

let $\mathbf{A}$ be the set of all $n\times n$ matrices on $\mathbb{N}_{n^2}=\{1,2,...,n^2\}$ with distinct entries.

let $T$ be the set of all permutations of $\mathbf{A}$ which swap the entry 1 with one of its adjacent entries. adjacent means one is above/below/right/left of the other (and both are neighbors).

Let $S$ be the permutation subgroup generated by $T$.

Show that $S$ acts ***intransitively*** on $\mathbf{A}$.

I'm a.s. it's correct for even $n$.

Comment: You mean each matrix has *distinct* entries, that is, all number from 1 to $n^2$ appear in each matrix? Or are repetitions allowed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a generalization of the famous [15-puzzle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/15_puzzle). The proof that it is not transitive is the same. To each matrix, associate the number given by 
\begin{equation}
\text{(block distance of 1 from upper left corner)} + 
\text{(parity of underlying permutation of $\mathbb{N}_{n^2}$)}.
\end{equation}
The parity of this number is an invariant under the allowed moves, that is, it does not change when you make a swap. So if you start with the numbers neatly ordered row by row, you will never get the matrix with 2 and 3 exchanged.

Comment: @CutieKrait thanks!

Comment: It seems that really the full permutation group generated is only the symmetric group $S_3$ on the three entries at upper left, to the right of that, and below it.

Comment: how about even $n$? for odd $n$ it may be transitive at least for $n=1$ it is.

Comment: see this: http://migo.sixbit.org/puzzles/fifteen/

Comment: I have mentioned 2 and 3 in the proof, thereby implicitly assuming $n > 1$.