# Is toggling action on a binary matrix transitive?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $M^{n\times n}(2)$ be the set of all $n\times n$ matrices on $\{0,1\}$.

$$T_{ij}:M^{n\times n}(2)\to M^{n\times n}(2)$$ is defined so that $T_{ij}(A)$ is $A$ with entries $$ij,(i-1)j,(i+1)j,i(j-1),i(j+1)$$
toggled (if they are valid entries).
$G$ is the permutation group generated by all $T_{ij}$ (where $1\leq i\leq n$ and $1\leq j\leq n$). Does $G$ act transitively on $M^{n\times n}(2)$?

Comment: What values of $i,j$ are you allowing? Must $(i,j)$ itself be a valid index (if not required, then you can toggle any individual bit on the border, and the answer is "transitive")? Must _all five_ positions be valid (in which case you cannot toggle the corners and the answer is "not transitive")?

Comment: yes all entries all valid. more precisely: $ij$ is valid iff $1\leq i,j\leq n$. And only for valid $ij$, $T_{ij}$ is defined. for a valid $ij$ if any one of the entries listed above is valid then $T_{ij}$ toggles it.

Comment: So you mean to answer "No not all five positions need to be valid, but position $(i,j)$ must be valid".

Comment: yes‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌.

Comment: The question is whether a particular family of $n^2$ square matrices over $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$ forms a generating set (and therefore a basis) of the vector space (over that field) of all such matrices. For this reason, and because the given tags were all inappropriate, I've retagged the question.

Comment: Maybe this question should have mentiond the "[Lights Off](https://live.gnome.org/Lightsoff)" game.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen: this question together with the [previous one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/290508/sorting-numbers-in-a-matrix-by-moving-an-empty-entry-through-other-entries-is-no) have something to do with board games simulated in computer and it was suggested by "game-theory" tag. However this one relates to digital topology too. regards.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen: I found something about that game: http://www.math.ksu.edu/~dmaldona/math551/lights_out.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To rephrase the question: let $G$ be the set of matrices $\{ C(i,j)\in M_{n,n}(\Bbb F_2)\mid i,j\in\{1,\ldots,n\}\,\}$ where $C(i,j)$ is the matrix with a coefficient $1$ at position $(i,j)$ and at the position above, below, left and right of $(i,j)$ as far as these lie inside the matrix; does this set of matrices span the $\Bbb F_2$-vector space $ M_{n,n}(\Bbb F_2)$? (If a given matrix $A$ can be written as a sum of a subset of the $C(i,j)$, then performing the toggles for this subset starting from the zero matrix will transofrm it into $A$, and the question is whether this is possible for all $A$.)

The answer is that it does not so for all $n$, although it does for certain values of $n$. Since the set has the same number $n^2$ of elements as the dimension of the vector space, generating the space means being a basis; then by contraposition finding any non-trivial relation between the given matrices shows that they cannot generate the whole space. Now for $n=4$ and $n=5$ the combinations indicated by the following matrices are examples of non-trivial relations:
$$
  \begin{pmatrix}0&1&1&1\\1&0&1&0\\1&1&0&0\\1&0&0&0\end{pmatrix}
\qquad\text{and}\qquad
\begin{pmatrix}1&1&0&1&1\\0&0&0&0&0\\1&1&0&1&1\\0&0&0&0&0\\1&1&0&1&1\end{pmatrix}
$$
The indicated set does form a basis for $n\leq3$ and for $6\leq n\leq8$. By looking closely at the given relation for $n=4$ one can derive one for $n=9$, and the example for $n=5$ generalises to all $n\equiv5\pmod6$, so that gives quite a few cases where the action is not transitive.

Looking, for the cases where the action *is* transitive, at the combinations that will flip a single entry does not suggest much of a pattern. For instance here is a combination that for $n=6$ will flip the $2,3$ entry:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&1&0&1&0\\
1&0&1&0&1&1\\
0&0&1&0&1&0\\
1&1&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&1&0\\
1&1&0&1&1&1
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

Comment: what is a non-trivial relation?

Comment: A relation is, in this setting, a set of operations whose net effect of zero, because every bit is toggled an even number of times. A trivial relation would be the empty set of operations, or more generally something where every basic operation is applied an even number of times; that gives a relation, but it isn't an interesting one.

Comment: please explain more this part: "finding any non-trivial relation between the given matrices shows that they cannot generate the whole space. Now for n=4 and n=5 the combinations indicated by the following matrices are examples of non-trivial relations:"

Comment: There are $N=n^2$ different operations, we can apply $2^N$ combinations of operations (since applying the same operation twice has no effect we use each operation $0$ or $1$ times), and starting from the zero matrix there are $2^N$ matrices that we want to reach. So if any non-empty combination of operations produces no effect at all, then there are also matrices that cannot be reached, by the pigeonhole principle (or by the dimension principle, because the set matrices we can reach will form a vector subspace). This is in fact the simplest way to show that there are unreachable matrices.

Comment: The matrices given are to be interpreted as combinations of operations: each entry $1$ means the operation that toggles that position and its direct neighbours. You can check that for the given relation matrices, for each position the sum of the entry at that position and its neighbours (which is the set of operations that will toggle the chosen position) is always even, so the position is unchanged after the given combination of operations. Since this holds for all positions, the net effect is zero,

Comment: nice‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌.